# c# Pointer of Pointer of char, char**

Tags: c#, pointers, char

I have this code (snipet) and it runs through and works, but after leaving the whole procedure `procedureInAClass()` and going on with next code it crashes: **"Bad_module_error"**.  I don't see the error.

```
public void procedureInAClass(){ //this code is in a Class, it works but after leaving whole procedure it crashes
char** comment=(char**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(char*)); //comment is in Code a class Member
string aval="some chars in a string";
SToCP(val,  comment) ; //value of String to *comment
CPToS(comment); //**comment to string
}

//this part is in a static class

    public static void SToCP(string s, char** c)//writes string s in *c
    {      
        *c = SToCP(s);
    }
    public static char* SToCP(string s) 
    {
        char* ret= (char*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal( sizeof(char) * (s.Length +1));
        int i;
        byte se = sizeof(char);
        for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            *(ret + se * i) = s[i];
        *(ret + s.Length * se) = '\0';
        return ret;
    }



public static String CPToS(char** c)
    { 
          return CPToS(*c); //passing the pointer char* which is holded by char** c
    }

public static String CPToS(char* c)
    {
        string ret = "";
        byte s = sizeof(char);//char is two bytes long
        int i = 0;
        while (*(c + s * i) != '\0')//zero terminated string
            ret += *(c + s * i++);
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are multiplying your index `i` by the `sizeof(char*)` but treating that as a `char*`.  Adding 1 to a char* adds the size of a char (2 bytes) to the pointer.  You were writing every other character, then continuing to overwrite memory after your string allocation because of going too far.

Try this instead:

```
public static char* SToCP(string s) {
    char* ret = (char*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(char) * (s.Length + 1));
    char* p = ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        *(p++) = s[i];            
    *(p++) = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Of course your `CPToS` method is also wrong, so if you fix `SToCP` to correctly not write over other character, you will need to fix `CPToS` as well otherwise it will return the wrong string back.

Here's a fixed version of `CPToS` to match:

```
public static String CPToS(char* c) {
            string ret = "";
            int i = 0;
            while (*(c +  i) != '\0')//zero terminated string
                ret += *(c +  i++);
            return ret;
        }
```

`SToCP` was causing the stack to be screwed up and causing the crash, though.